# StencilJS styling other components

Tags: stenciljs

I have a simple component being called from another component that I was to add a margin value to.

Example:

Child component:

```
import { Component } from '@stencil/core';


@Component({
  tag: 'app-header',
  styleUrl: 'app-header.css',
  shadow: false
})
export class AppHeader {

  render() {
    return (
      <div class='app-header-component'>
        Hey I'm a header
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The parent component

```
import { Component } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'app-home',
  styleUrl: 'app-home.css'
})
export class AppHome {

  render() {
    return (
      <div class='app-home'>
        <app-header></app-header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Parent component styles

```
// app-home.css

app-header {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

How could I apply styles to a child component?

**EDIT**

I realized I can target the components child and then apply the styles.

```
// app-home.css

app-header {
    .app-header-component {
        margin-top: 1rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add to the child component:

```
// app-header.css
app-header {
  display: block;
}
```

By default, Custom Elements are `display: inline`, which probably is affecting your styling.

Comment: You're right that did work. I ended up just switching to use shadow dom with css variables seems to be the cleanest solution